# About absolute convergence of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

[image]

I know I need to incorporate uniqueness theorem of Dirichlet series to get some kind of contradiction, but don't know how to proceed?

Comment: What did you try? Do you see a relation to the roots of $|a_m|m^{Re(s)}-\sum_{n>m}|a_n|n^{-Re(s)}$?

Comment: no can you explain @LutzL

Comment: Using the triangle inequality, $|a+b+c|\ge |a|-|b|-|c|$ etc. This works the same way as the diverse root bounds for polynomials. Show that for $Re(s)>c$ and greater than the given fraction, the function value is decidedly non-zero.

Comment: @LutzL Can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

In analogy, for a polynomial $p(z)=a_mz^m+...+a_1z+a_0$ and some number $R>0$, if $|z|>R$, then $1\le R^{-1}|z|$ so that
$$
|a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+...+a_1z+a_0|\le \left(|a_{m-1}|+|a_{m-2}|R^{-1}+...+|a_0|R^{m-1}\right)\cdot |z|^{m-1} = A_R\cdot |z|^{m-1}.
$$
Then by the triangle inequality
$$
|p(z)|\ge|z|^{m-1}\left(|a_m||z|-A_R\right).
$$
Thus if additional to $|z|>R$ also
$$
|z|>\frac{A_R}{|a_m|},
$$
then $z$ can not be a root of $p$. Or in other words, any root of $p$ satisfies
$$
|z|\le\max\left(R,\frac1{|a_m|}\left(|a_{m-1}|+|a_{m-2}|R^{-1}+...+|a_0|R^{m-1}\right)\right).
$$

---

To prove your claim, you have to follow similar steps. If $Re(s)>c$, then for $n>m$ $$|n^{s}|=n^{Re(s)}= n^{c}n^{Re(s)-c}\ge n^{c}(m+1)^{Re(s)-c},$$ 
which implies for the tail of the considered series the bound
$$
\left|\sum_{n>m}a_nn^s\right|\le (m+1)^{c-Re(s)}\sum_{n>m}|a_n|n^c=A_c\,(m+1)^{-Re(s)}
$$
By the triangle inequality we get 
$$
|f(s)|\ge |a_m|m^{-Re(s)}-A_c\,(m+1)^{-Re(s)}.
$$
As $A$ is finite by assumption, the second term can become smaller than the first term. If that is the case, then $|f(s)|>0$, so $s$ can not be a root of $f$. This dominance condition is equivalent to
$$
\left(\frac{m+1}{m}\right)^{Re(s)}>\frac{A_c}{|a_m|}.
$$
After taking the logarithm and isolating $Re(s)$, the claim results.

Comment: How this step guarantee  f is non-zero in half plane

Comment: We take p(z)=f(z) which have this kind of form right?

Comment: Instead of $\sum a_nz^n$ your series $\sum a_nn^{-s}$ has different terms. This difference you need to incorporate into the general strategy of dividing the series into head and tail and determining where the head term dominates the tail sum.

Comment: Please explain it I don't get it